# Visual Studio Web Publish causes VPN connection to disconnect

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vpn, one-click-web-publishing

I have a web application project in Visual Studio 2010 SP1. It publishes correctly when I am working from the office. However, when working remotely using a VPN connection, the VPN connection disconnects a few seconds after the Start Preview operation is started. Any ideas why the VPN drops?

I am using the [Web Publish Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj161045).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by switching to different VPN software on both the server and client.